# How to handle badge count If user delete/clear the notification from the server in ios?

Tags: ios, ipad, apple-push-notifications

Currently I am implementing an ios app with the server push notification.

I am successfully able to send push notifications with badge.
Badge count will be incremented from the server. If user opens the application from notification, it will reset count on the server.

Now the query is if user is not opening application from notification and deleting/clearing all notifications. 
That means there will be no notification so when app will be opened from the background it wont find any notification and so it will not reset the count on server and also not the badge value on app icon.

So how can i resolve this issue?

Comment: How are you incrementing the count when the user is opening your app from the notification?

Comment: If user opening app from notification then I am setting application badge number to 0 and also setting 0 to server. So next time server will again start with 0.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever application hits appDidBecomeActive delegate, clear the badge count to zero.

Comment: But it will set it to "0" every time and the notifications remain in the notification bar. So It's not the proper solution.

Comment: Setting applicationIconBadgeNumber to zero will clear notifications from notification tray.

Answer (score 0):

Use custom notification icon and maintain read and unread counts with in the app,you will not manage badge counts from push notifications when user remove and open notifications in the app.

Comment: But how am I able to get counts of the total notifications in the notification bar? when my app is close? and I will open it from app icon and not from the notification?

Comment: you get notification count when appDidBecomeActive like this [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber

Comment: applicationIconBadgeNumber count will increase your app will not active in background.\

Comment: Use two more web service for get unread count and update read count in  the app

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, the only way your app is getting the relevant data is if the user clicks on the notification. I'm assuming you're sending a custom payload of some kind. Though I don't know the nature of your app at all, I would say this is really not the way to go specifically because of the problem you're encountering - you have no way of knowing if/when the user clears notifications in the Notification Center and if they do, that data is forever lost to your app.

I would recommend your app request the new data from your server upon launch - ie/ get anything new since last time the app was opened - this way it's independent of whether the push was received or not and depending on what your server sends back, you can clear the push count (or not).